# SIMDify an function

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

I would need a help with SIMD-ifing these particular function.

I am just learning SIMD and SSE and all the benefits that come with it so your help would be

great. Thanks

```
void block_8x8(uint8_t *block1, 
               uint8_t *block2, 
               int stride, 
               int *result)

{   

*result = 0;

    int u,v;

    for (v=0; v<8; ++v)
        for (u=0; u<8; ++u)
            *result += abs(block2[v*stride+u] - block1[v*stride+u]);
}
```

Comment: Is this called for any particular values of `stride`?

Comment: No. I think that there are no particular values for stride.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an SSE (Intel)/MMX+ (AMD) version.

```
void block_8x8(uint8_t *block1, 
               uint8_t *block2, 
               int stride, 
               int *result)

{   
    const __m64 sad0 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad1 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad2 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad3 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad4 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad5 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad6 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    const __m64 sad7 = _mm_sad_pu8(*((const __m64*)(block1)), *((const __m64*)(block2)));

    *result = _mm_cvtsi64_si32(_mm_add_pi32(
        _mm_add_pi32(
            _mm_add_pi32(sad0, sad1),
            _mm_add_pi32(sad2, sad3)
        ),
        _mm_add_pi32(
            _mm_add_pi32(sad4, sad5),
            _mm_add_pi32(sad6, sad7)
        )
    ));
    _mm_empty();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to break due to misaligned loads ?

Comment: There is no aligned load instruction in MMX (and __m64 maps to mmx register), so all loads are potentially misaligned.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I've only ever used 128 bit SIMD on x86 (i.e. SSE2 and up) and wasn't aware that you could do this with 64 bit SIMD.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and see how it will do with the profiler.

Comment: Since this is the only answer I want to say thank you and your answer is marked as right one.